# how can i move lines in mulitple text files?

Tags: text-processing

Hi assume I have a files that look like:

```
x
x
x
A
B
C
1
2
3
D
E
F
x
x
x
```

and what need the files to look like:

```
x
x
x
A
B
C
D
E
F
1
2
3
x
x
x
```

I know I could do this with a few `sed -i s/search/replace/g` lines but am wondering if there's a better, easier way to move `x` number of rows by `y` numbers in either direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ed

```
echo -e '7,9m12\n,p' | ed -s file.txt
```

Comment: this solution works only under bash, it doesn't work under other environments

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` (moving rows down, because that's easiest with stream editors):

```
$ sed '7,9{H;d;}; 12{G;s/\n//;}' <file
x
x
x
A
B
C
D
E
F
1
2
3
x
x
x
```

You may read the `sed` script as "move lines 7 through to 9 to after line 12".

The script annotated:

```
7,9{            # These are the lines we'd like to move
    H;          # Append them to the hold space (separated by newlines)
    d;          # Delete from pattern space, start next cycle
}
12{             # This is where we'd like to move those lines
    G;          # Append the hold space
    s/\n//;     # Remove the newline that the above command inserted
}
                # (implicit print)
```

Since lines may be addressed by regular expressions (not just line numbers), the following would work too (on this particular data):

```
sed '/^1/,/^3/{H;d;}; /^F/{G;s/\n//;}' <file
```

I.e., "move the lines from the one starting with `1` through to the one starting with `3` to after the line that starts with `F`".

---

A direct translation of the above into `awk`:

```
awk '/^1/,/^3/ { hold = hold ORS $0; next }
     /^F/      { $0 = $0 hold }
               { print }' <file
```

Using "line numbers" (record numbers in `awk`):

```
awk 'NR == 7, NR == 9 { hold = hold ORS $0; next }
     NR == 12         { $0 = $0 hold }
                      { print }' <file
```

The condition `NR == 7, NR == 9` could also be written `NR >= 7 && NR <= 9`.

To be 100% faithful to the `sed` code, the second block should read `{ $0 = $0 ORS hold; sub(ORS, "", $0) }` but it's a bit silly to insert the output record separator (a newline by default) only to remove it immediately afterwards.

---

To replace the original file with the result of the above commands:

```
sed ...as above... <file >newfile && mv newfile file
```

or the same thing with the `awk` command.

This would leave the original file unaltered if the input file of `sed`/`awk` could not be read, or if the output file could not be written.

Comment: robust solution thumb up!